# SAS: When performing ARIMA modeling and forecasting, how do you specify interval for stock prices since you would be missing days?

Tags: sas, arima

forecast in arima asks for an interval and id which in my case is interval=day and id=date. However, stock closing prices aren't reported on weekends and I get errors stating that. How do I specify the interval in that case?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but when I've run into this issue I simply created a new variable that can be used as a proxy for the date (that doesn't contain gaps).  When presenting data back, be sure to use the date column and not the proxy column.

For example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by stock;
  retain proxy_date .;

  if first.stock then do;
    proxy_date = 1;
  end;
  else do;
    proxy_date = sum(proxy_date,1);
  end;
run;
```